# magento 1.9 sample data download problems

Tags: magento-1.9

MageStackDayNeedsYou, do you also have the link for the sample data(for magento 1.9.0.1) as well ? i would really appreciate if you can put the link on here, thanks –

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the magento commerce web site at:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce

Comment: thank you, but i meant if there is a source other than the magento website, for some reason i am not able to download it from the magento site, it only downloads a portion of it and then says done